# Styling soft input action button color

Tags: android

Is it somehow possible to style the soft input action button color? I am using theme appcompat with:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

So the `EditText`otherwise is styled with my primary color(hint text color in TextInputLayout, cut and copy handles etc.) but they keyboard action button remains green in Marshmallow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible (as of now) to have your primary colour (or any colour for that matter) set as the Soft Input action key colour. The most you could do is change what it is supposed to do by specifying the ime options. Sorry!

Comment: Any idea if I can have my own icon with soft input?

Comment: Nope, this is all you can do: [Handling Keyboard Input](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/index.html)

Comment: Hopefully they someday get the icon support there as well.

Comment: Hopefully. Android is very customisable. Sadly, the keyboard isn't much so.  :(

Comment: Is this still the case now?